# Android Opengl Crash

Tags: android, image, canvas, opengl-es, bitmap

I have an integrated Android gpu image library for image processing and I am getting the below crash on some Android devices. If it is a problem with recycling the bitmap then it should crash on all devices, shouldn't it?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@41c523e8
at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1047)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1087)
at pm.run(SourceFile:214)
at pi.onDrawFrame(SourceFile:113)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1463)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1217)
```

In most of the Android devices it is working fine, but this problem happens only on some devices. Provide your suggestions to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It propably doesn't crash on all devices because of one of the following issues:

- Prior to Android 3.0, Bitmap data is not held in VM memory but in native memory and if you recycle a bitmap, you actually don't know when the bitmap data will be removed. (See: [Managing Bitmap Data](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html))
- But even on devices with Android 3.0 and higher, the bitmap data will be removed by the garbage collector sometime in the future.

So perhaps you are just lucky and you can still access bitmap even though recycle was called.
Then it would be just because the garbage collector didn't run, yet.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the link.